# problemas con caracteres en xml

Tags: xml

tengo un problema al enviar y abrir un xml.
En el xml necesito que me aparezca:

`"Comisiones por Captaci&gt;#243;n"`

pero cuando lo envío o lo abro me aparece `"Comisiones por Captaci>#243;n"`

He probado con la codificacion

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

A ver si alguien me puede ayudar. Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo de que quieres que se muestre así

```
"Comisiones por Captaci&gt;#243;n"
```

Y tenemos o existen **5 caracteres de escape** en xml:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el código debería ponerse así:

```
Comisiones por Captaci&amp;gt;#243;n
```

Para verse así..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

P.d. Espero que sea lo que estés buscando. Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

El código html que estas usando para representar la ó acentuada no es el correcto

```
>#243;
```

debes usar `&#243;`, por ejemplo :

> ```
> Comisiones por Captaci&#243;n
> ```

de esta forma al representarse se mostrará :

> Comisiones por Captación

---

Estos son los códigos html para palabras acentuadas:

```
á = &#225;   

é = &#233;   

í = &#237;  

ó = &#243;

ú = &#250;    

ñ = &#241;
```

En esta lista puedes ver todos los códigos:

[Tabla de códigos HTML](https://ascii.cl/es/codigos-html.htm)

Comment: lo que quiero es que sea vea

     &#225; y no el acento